# requestTemplates and responseTemplates not working in AWS API Gateway SAM template

Tags: aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I am having a problem getting the requestTemplates and responseTemplates I define to work.

The relevant piece of my (processed) template is here:

```
/cse:
            options:
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                type: mock
                requestTemplates:
                  application/json: |
                    {
                      "statusCode" : 200
                    }
                responses:
                  default:
                    statusCode: '200'
                    responseTemplates:
                      application/json: |
                        {}
                    responseParameters:
                      method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '''*'''
                      method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: '''GET,OPTIONS'''
              summary: CORS support
              responses:
                '200':
                  headers:
                    Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
                      schema:
                        type: string
                    Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
                      schema:
                        type: string
                  description: Default response for CORS method
            get:
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                httpMethod: POST
                requestTemplates:
                  application/json: |
                    {
                      "body": $input.json('$'),
                      "headers": {
                        #foreach($header in $input.params().header.keySet())
                        "$header": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().header.get($header))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
                          #end
                      },
                      "method": "$context.httpMethod",
                      "params": {
                        #foreach($param in $input.params().path.keySet())
                        "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().path.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
                          #end
                      },
                      "query": {
                        #foreach($queryParam in $input.params().querystring.keySet())
                        "$queryParam": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().querystring.get($queryParam))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
                          #end
                      }
                    }
                type: aws
                responses:
                  default:
                    statusCode: 200
                    responseTemplates:
                      text/html: $input.path('$')
                    responseParameters:
                      method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '''*'''
                      method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: '''GET,OPTIONS'''
                uri: !Sub >-
                  arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${CSELambda.Arn}/invocations
              responses:
                '200':
                  headers:
                    Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
                      type: string
                    Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
                      type: string
                  description: OK
```

The `options` bit is auto-generated by AWS by adding a `Cors` entry in the template and works fine.
See how it defines a `responseTemplates` and `requestTemplates` and it works.

The `get` bit is the one I am trying to get to work. As far as I can tell, I am following the same format as the auto-generated `options` bit, but the API Gateway is not setting these 2 templates, and I am at a loss.

Been Googling, trying different things to no avail, so far. Any help appreciated.